# xamarin - avoid open InfoWindow on android marker

Tags: android, xamarin, infowindow

In my app I want to avoid opening infowindos on some marker. 
I tried to add

```
   NativeMap.MarkerClick += (sender, e) => OnMarkerClick(sender, e);
```

and in the On marker click I undestend to return false or true if infowindos have to show or not.

```
        public bool OnMarkerClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if ("MY Condition on e.Marker")
            // I need to: NO open InfoWindows
                return true;
            else
            // I need to: OPEN InfoWindows
                return false;
        }
```

but the result is de same. Infowindows is not opening.
There is another way to do that?

Comment: Can you provide detailed info about your issue here?

Comment: I actualize my question